# Reading any word in a line from docx document using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to search for words in docx document using vb.net but the code only reads the first word in the line and then proceeds to read the first word in the next line. for eg.

- Line 1 - Mathew
- Line 2 - Mark
- Line 3 - Luke

But I would like for vb.net to to read words in a single line when I give a search. For eg.

- Line 1 - I am Mike. I am proficient in Excel.
- Line 2 - Excel is quite handy to use.
- Line 3 - I am not sure Excel can handle everything.

In the above line when I run a search for the word "Excel" the code should be able to tell me how many instances of excel is found in that file and which lines they can be found on.

I am a newbie in vb.net so if an answer has already been provided for such a question as this please can you redirect me to that page or link or help me with the codes that can help generate my request.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Hi Daniel...sorry for getting back so late...internet outage at home and restrictions on internet use at work...but below is the code I had used...please note that this was something I searched the web for...but my query did not give me any solution while searching...maybe I wasnt searching the right way?!

Comment: Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
        objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'objWordApp.Visible = True

Comment: Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Bible\Bible\bin\Debug\Bible.docx")
        Dim findText As String = TextBox1.Text
        objDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting()

Comment: Try
            If objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(findText) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Text is found")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("The text could not be found.")

            End If
            objDoc.Close()
            objWordApp.Quit()

        Catch ex As Exception

            objDoc.Close()

            objWordApp.Quit()

        End Try

Comment: Can you update your question please? i can't read unformatted code!